# When reviewing low quality posts, make leaving a comment be considered an action

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, low-quality-posts

I was working through some of the Low Quality Posts review queue when I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22232839/542517).

The answer is simply a snippet of code that, in fact, does try to solve the issue of the question. However, it is of low quality. Now, I could recommend deletion for it being low-quality, but it really should just be expanded on by the poster, if possible. Therefore, instead of choosing to recommend deletion, I decided to leave a comment on it asking the poster to expand on it to improve the quality of their answer.

*(Perhaps this is where a debate will come in. Maybe I should just recommend deletion?)*

To me, the act of leaving a comment is an action that I have taken on the post while in the review queue. However, now to move on to the next post, I still have to click one of the action buttons.

- **Looks Good** - Well, no, the answer doesn't look good. It should be expanded on it.
- **Edit** - It's formatted well but any other changes would be radical.
- **Recommend Deletion** - I don't feel it should be deleted, just improved.
- **Skip** - Skip this review task on move on. Seems like the only logical choice.

However, if I click **Skip**, it is not counted as if I reviewed the item, even though I *did* by leaving a comment. I think this should be addressed.

**Proposal**

While in the Low Quality Posts review queue, if you leave a comment on a post and then chose **Skip**, it should increment your progress instead of ignoring it as it does now. Additionally, perhaps when you successfully leave a comment on the post, the **Skip** button changes to say **Next** to indicate you have taken action on the post.

Comment: Skip is never an action. If you don't think a post needs to be deleted right away (which I am assuming you didn't), then "looks good" is the right response

Comment: Personally I think the "Looks Good" button is named wrong. It is confusing

Comment: @psubsee2003 I agree. Perhaps just changing the text on that button would be a good fix.

Comment: Seems like low-quality review should be like the late answers queue -- allowing votes (particularly down) and multiple actions before clicking "I'm done".

Comment: @JoshCaswell it's more just a mis-understanding of the meaning of the buttons though.  If downvoting, or adding a comment, is enough that you feel the post is no longer "so bad that it warrants deletion", then "looks good" is the right button.  "Looks good" doesn't actually mean, "this is a good post", it means, "this isn't so completely awful that we need to delete it".  We just need a way of conveying that in something that fits on a button.

Comment: @Servy: Maybe "Good enough"?